# Split an array and organize the values

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP array:

```
$b = array
(
    0 =>"03xxx", //Index of main,  substr(index,0,2)

        1 =>"04xxx",
        2 =>"05xxx",
        //3 =>"06xxx" // missing "06" 
        //4 =>"07xxx",

        6 =>"04xxx",
        7 =>"05xxx",
        8 =>"06xxx",
        //9 =>"07xxx"

    10 =>"08xxx",

    11 =>"03xxx" ,// new index of main

        12 =>"04xxx",
        13 =>"05xxx",
        14 =>"06xxx",

        //15 =>"07xxx" missing "07"
    16 =>"08xxx"
);
```

I need to transform it to:

```
/*the expected result 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03xxx04xxx05xxx          08xxx, // missing 06 ,07
            [1] => 03xxx04xxx05xxx06xxx     08xxx // missing 07 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03xxx04xxx05xxx06xxx     08xxx // missing 07
        )

)
*/
```

**Update:**

Based on [yes123's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251851/split-an-array-and-organized-the-values/6252270#6252270) I arrived at the following solution:

```
/*
 * thank to @yes123 
*/
function transform($a){
    $result=array();
    $i=0;
    $j=0;
    $last = 2;
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
        if (!isset($result[$i]))
            $result[$i]=array('');


        if ( ++$last != $v[1])
            $result[$i][$j] .=  str_repeat(str_pad(" ",5),($v[1]-$last));

        $result[$i][$j] .= $v;

        $last = $v[1];

        if (substr($v,0,2)=='08') {
            $last=3;
            $j++;
        }

        if ($a[$k+1][1]=='3') {
            $last=2;
            $i++;
            $j=0;
        }
    }
    return $result;
    }
```

Comment: oh my god, what is that?

Comment: ***GREAT WALL OF CODE***

Comment: considering I understood what you needed I answered this with a pretty good script I believe. Give me those point XD

Comment: I am trying here http://codepad.org/zjsb9fgA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch it live here: http://codepad.org/SWOur3HD version(0.4)

Here is the source code just in case the link dies:

```
<?php

$a = array
(
    0 =>"03xxx", //Index of main,  substr(index,0,2)

    1 =>"04xxx",
    //2 =>"05xxx",
    //3 =>"06xxx" // missing "06" 
    4 =>"07xxx",
    5 =>"08xxx",

    6 =>"04xxx",
    7 =>"05xxx",
    8 =>"06xxx",
    //9 =>"07xxx" 
    10 =>"08xxx",

    11 =>"03xxx" ,// new index of main

    12 =>"04xxx",
    13 =>"05xxx",
    14 =>"06xxx",
    //15 =>"07xxx" missing "07"
    16 =>"08xxx"
);


$result=array();
$i=0;
$j=0;
$last = 2;
$main='';
$addMain=false;
foreach($a as $k=>$v) {

  if($v[1]=='3')
    $main=$v;

  if (!isset($result[$i]))
    $result[$i]=array('');

  if ( ++$last != $v[1])
    $result[$i][$j] .=  str_repeat('     ',($v[1]-$last));

  if ($addMain) {
    $result[$i][$j] .= $main;
    $addMain=false;
  }

  $result[$i][$j] .= $v;

  $last = $v[1];

  if ($v[1]=='8') {
    $last=3;
    $j++;
    if ($a[$k+1][1]!='3')
      $addMain=true;
  }

  if ($a[$k+1][1]=='3') {
    $last=2;
    $i++;
    $j=0;
    $addMain=false;
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

Anyway keep in mind next time you code: <strike>Simple is Beautiful</strike> (not anymore now lol)

Comment: Yes,you understand my question,here ,but you missing multi-dim array.because "03" is the main and "04" is the sub.

Comment: if you dont mine this what I am trying to achiev,http://codepad.org/zjsb9fgA Look your idea simple than mine,L)

Comment: @newbie: got it give me couple of sec. if you don't mind think to +1 to incentive me ^^

Comment: should be fixed now. the only thing is on the second submain you don't find repeated the  `03xxx ` main code. Dunno if you really need that

Comment: @yes123 what's food you eat,why you so cleaver like this? and so me ^^ .thank so much

Comment: if missing more than two elements i.e "06" "07" at the same time problems.I am trying to check it ,too,:)

Comment: @newbie: yes there is that possibility but you didn't mention it in first question xD. Open a new question i will write it there if you need so we can keep stuff lighter

Comment: you code like a magic,that I could not understand,if I ask the same questions most people will link me to this answer.

Comment: Your code still have problems,maybe I have to add one more question.

Comment: missing "03" at array[0][1] .BTW I added http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253811/transform-array-and-reorganize-the-elements

Comment: Yes i wrote about that in a previous comment i thought it was not a problem anyway i will fix that later. Cant now

Comment: now I am lost a lot down-vote :( I try to do it by myself ,but I cannot

Comment: Delete the other qiestion. I will reppy here when i come back

Comment: @newbie: updated 0.4 version. I have added that last thing. Also note that now the function it's pretty more complex than before. Next time never use such an awful structure.

Comment: I see you base array is difference from mine,because my arrays there is only one "08 "between "03->08" and your there are two 08.thank you so much to spent your  time solve and help me.

Comment: It too shame to ask help again and again.your input is differences from my given array.

Comment: In my code there are two 08 because your first array was like so.. Man really change your structure. Because it's almost impossible now without a clear delimiter

Comment: I can't change it because with your new specs I should totally rewrite it. I have already wrote **4 versions** for you. Next time be more careful with your first question. Sorry

Comment: @yes123,please you listen this song before you go ,father and son is the title of the song ,.and waiting for your love.that i have waiting until now.thankss

Comment: @yes123 Could you help me one more time please.because I try all my best ,I could not.thanks

Comment: @yes123 +1 for the combo-breaker :p